# Remove Master Boot Code but leave Partition Table?

Tags: editing, mbr

For testing purposes, I need to fidget with the MBR on a Windows7 test host: I'd like to remove the Master Boot Code but leave the Partition Table within.

Does the following Linux command do this, or does it wipe out the entire MBR, including the Partition Table?

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hda bs=512 count=1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That command will remove the partition table. If you want to remove the MBR and keep the partition table:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hda bs=446 count=1
```

See [Wikipedia's MBR page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) for the MBR layout.  The primary partition table starts at byte 446 (counting from zero).

Comment: to be on the safe side i'd use `bs=440`, tho i'm not sure if windows uses that 4-byte optional disk signature area as signature or the tail end of its boot code.

Comment: Booting with a Debian 2.6.32-based live USB Linux, I "sudo -s" to root, and ran the command... but it says "0 bytes copied", although I checked that the /sda partition is not mounted. Has someone seen this?

Comment: Do you have a SATA drive or IDE drive?

Comment: SATA, so I ran "dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sda bs=440 count=1". There is no error message; It just says "0+0 records in, 0+0 records out, 0 bytes (0 B) copied"

Comment: Found it: "if=/dev/zero" worked, while "if=/dev/null" does nothing. Thanks.

Comment: right.  pulling data from /dev/null probably gets an immediate EOF.

Comment: Woah. It seems `parted` 3.2 gets very confused if it is told to examine a stick which has grub2 bootloader code in the MBR. It is incapable of finding the partition records... `fdisk`, however correctly ignores the bootloader code. Zeroing the bootloader code out allows `parted` to find the partition records, too.